SharedTransition lookaheadRoot has not been initialized
Using SharedTransitions in Jetpack compose, I got the following error :
FATAL EXCEPTION: main (Ask Gemini)
Process: com.example.bacasable, PID: 10130
kotlin.UninitializedPropertyAccessException: lateinit property lookaheadRoot has not been initialized
x
The Code used is as followed :
class MainActivity : ComponentActivity() {

@OptIn(ExperimentalMaterial3Api::class, ExperimentalSharedTransitionApi::class)
override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
    //enableEdgeToEdge()
    setContent {

        val navController = rememberNavController()

        KoinAndroidContext {
            Scaffold(
                topBar = {
                    ...
                },
            ) { innerPadding ->


                Box(
                    modifier = Modifier
                        .fillMaxSize()
                ) {
                    SharedTransitionScope {
                        NavHost(
                            navController = navController,
                            startDestination = "list"
                        )
                        {
                            composable(
                                route = "detail/{resId}/{index}/{text}",
                                arguments = listOf(
                                    navArgument("resId") {
                                        type = NavType.StringType
                                    },
                                    navArgument("text") {
                                        type = NavType.StringType
                                    },
                                )
                            )
                            {
                       
                                val resId = it.arguments?.getString("resId") ?: ""
                                val index = it.arguments?.getInt("index") ?: 0
                                val text = it.arguments?.getString("text") ?: ""
                                DetailScreen(
                                    resId = resId,
                                    index = index,
                                    text = text,
                                    animatedVisibilityScope = this
                                )
                            }
                            composable("list") {
                                ListScreen(
                                    onItemClick = { resId, index, text ->
                                        navController.navigate("detail/$resId/$index/$text")
                                    },
                                    animatedVisibilityScope = this
                                )
                            }
                        }
                    }
                }

            }

        }
    }
}
}


I mistakenly used SharedTransitionScope instead of SharedTransitionLayout
